# Creating "groups" in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, contacts-group

How do I make a group contact in Gmail?

I want to email everyone in the office and have an "office" group that will email all the people in this group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Contacts
2. Click the `New Group` button: "+" with 2 people.
3. Give it a name and click ok.
4. Go back to My Contacts (or whichever grouping is appropriate) and select users.
5. On the right, click `Groups` and select the group to add to.
6. Compose an email and use the group name in the To field

Answer (score 0):

In Google Contacts, create a group then add people to this group. When you compose your email, this group will expand to individual email addresses.